# Error: Cannot find module 'shrink-ray'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yeoman

After using the amazing [angular-fullstack-generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) though [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), I followed the setup instructions, and when I came to running `npm start` or `gulp serve` I got the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'shrink-ray'`

Seemed pretty self-explanitory, so I ran `npm install shrink-ray`, and doing so gave me the following error:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Releas
e/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz                                            
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.9.2 (
node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)                         
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, pleas
e add the "/m" switch.                                                               
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To f 
ix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2 
005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed el 
sewhere.  [C:\Users\alicia.sykes\Dropbox\Coding\Angular\team-awesome\node_modules\no 
de-zopfli\build\binding.sln]
```

Again, this error looked pretty self-explanatory, so I followed the steps it suggested - but it didn't work. The same error always returned, preventing me from installing `shrink-ray`.

After many hours of Googling, it looked like a combination of issues between:

- `node-gyp`
- The NPM and node version installed
- C++ build tools (why, I have no idea)
- Having the Python environmental variable pointing to
  the correct installation location of either Python 2.7 or 3.1

Some of these factors modified the error message - but none were the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution was in fact simple:
>
> **(as admin/sudo) run: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`**
>
> *This was provided by the very helpful [Adonay28](https://github.com/adonay28) on this GitHub
>   issue, here:
>   https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2462#issuecomment-275112118*

For this to work, you do also need to have:

- Python 2.7 or 3.1 installed
- The latest version of npm (`4.5.0` works). Run: `npm i npm -g` to update.
- And node-gyp installed globally. Run `npm install -g node-gyp`

Hope this helps someone else, to get there app running quicker thank I did!